# OpenFileDialog and UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm developing a tool that processes an .fbx model and user input into a single file for use in a game. The code for when the user presses the "Import Model" button is as follows, and is similar for every button:

```
private void E_ImportModelButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    E_model = null; // byte array where model is stored
    E_SelectedFileLabel.Text = "No Model Selected"; // label on form
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "FBX Model (.fbx)|*.fbx";
    ofd.Multiselect = false;
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // adjusts variables for game file
        string s = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName);
        E_model = File.ReadAllBytes(s);
        E_SelectedFileLabel.Text = "File Selected: " + ofd.FileName;
    }
}
```

The problem is, whenever I click OK, an `UnauthorizedAccessException` occurs. I have tried importing files from `C:\Users\Owner\Downloads` as well as `C:\Users\Owner\Desktop` and the `C:\` drive itself, but it still occurs. What could I add to this code to gain access to these (and other) folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read from directory via the method intended to read from a file:

```
string s = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName);
E_model = File.ReadAllBytes(s);
```

Replace it with:

```
E_model = File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't ready the directory, you have to read a file:

```
string s = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName);
E_model = File.ReadAllBytes(s);
```

Try adding the file name here